# How can I fix my UEFI boot menu after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, uefi, hp

After installing Ubuntu, I used the tool boot-repair to get my laptop to load grub upon startup. Unfortunately, after a while, I have noticed that I can no longer boot from a flash drive (to reinstall windows or another linux distro) because the boot menu is filled up with Ubuntu entries. The UEFI firmware is behaving oddly and I'm scared that I will end up with a brick unable to boot any OS.

[Boot-repair info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5892243/)

[image]

All options including "OS Boot Manager" take me to grub. The list does not scroll. From looking at the Windows 8 advanced reboot menus I know there are more options hidden down there. My settings indicate that secure boot is disabled. However, when I boot the flash drive from Windows 8's advanced reboot menu I get a message indicating that my computer will not boot from it (if you need the exact text I can try that again).

I imagine fixing this involves removing those extra entries from some EFI boot partition or something. Thanks in advance for your help.

My laptop is a HP Envy Spectre XT.

Answer (score 1):

The extra Ubuntu entries probably aren't related to your problem, but I could be wrong. Certainly I've heard of weirder EFI problems. Thus, you might as well address it. To do so, first type `sudo efibootmgr` in Ubuntu. This should produce a list like this:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0002,0003,0001
Boot0000* rEFInd Boot Manager
Boot0001* fedora
Boot0002* rEFInd (via PreLoader)
Boot0003* ubuntu
```

These entries are from one of my systems, and of course yours will be different -- it will probably have a large number of `ubuntu` entries. Take note of the `BootOrder` list -- it identifies the order in which entries are tried. Chances are one of your `ubuntu` entries will be first on that list, or at least very early on it. You can delete all of the other `ubuntu` entries with efibootmgr, as in:

```
sudo efibootmgr -b 0003 -B
```

That command deletes entry `Boot0003` (which is the only `ubuntu` entry in my example).

Once that's done, try again to boot a USB flash drive. If you can't do it, try using the `Boot From EFI File` option shown in your screen shot; that may enable you to select a file on your USB flash drive.

It's also conceivable that there's a setting in your firmware that's disabling USB flash drive access. On one of my computers, for instance, there's an option to do a quick USB initialization that prepares USB keyboards but not USB storage devices. If that option is enabled, it becomes impossible to boot from a USB flash drive. Thus, such options must be set to do a full USB initialization at boot time. (Check your USB flash drive's access lights as you boot; if they don't flash, chances are the firmware is *not* initializing the device.)

If all this fails, it's conceivable that installing [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) will help; in theory, it should produce a list of bootable USB devices. This will only work if the USB devices are initialized, though.

Comment: This is my output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5892822/
Any more insight before I try to run those commands you suggested?

Comment: None your `Ubuntu` entries is in the `BootOrder`. My guess is that you're booting through a copy of GRUB installed as `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` on the ESP and accessed through the `Boot3000` entry. You've also got a lot of (apparently duplicated) `EFI Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk` entries. I recommend removing all but the first of the `Ubuntu` entries and all but the first of the `EFI Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk` entries. You *do* have an entry labelled `USB Hard Drive - KingstonDT 101 G2`. My guess is it appears on a second screen of options in your boot manager.